# Change margins in Internet Explorer when printing from BAT file

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, batch-file

Does anyone know how I can change margins when I print from Internet Explorer from a `bat` file? When I print from browser,  page is printed without margins, however when I print from `bat` margins are put. In registry IE margins are set to 0, also in printer properties margins are set to 0.
Printing from `bat` using this guy example (PrintHTM.bat, Version 2.00)
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/printfiles.php#PrintHTM2

Comment: I suppose you mean Internet Explorer and not good old `copy foo.txt con` from MS-DOS days and edited the question accordingly.

Comment: ty. but problem happens when printing html file from bat file. When i print it opened in IE or Chrome, there are no margins put and i do not change these browsers settings